# What is the best way to retopologize a beveled corner to get rid of beveled pinch

Tags: modeling, retopology

I used a bevel modifier and now I have pinched corner, what is the best way to retopologize a 1 segment bevel corner. It is a pretty simple object I am just practicing retopolgy.

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots https://we.tl/t-1Q5QAtpbDC here you go

Comment: it seems to work fine if I use the topology you show, I've just enabled Auto Smooth: https://zupimages.net/up/22/01/oh61.jpg

Comment: @moonboots I  was just just trying to see if there was a way to retopo it, the way it is now the corners are pinched and it makes unwrapping more difficult

Comment: I can't see any pinching though (see my photo)